# Does having so many macros (#define) increase compilation time due to prolonged pre-processing?

Tags: c++, c, macros, profiling, compilation

In a very simplistic way, I understand:

```
"Compilation" = "Pre-processing" + "Parsing" + "Linking" + "Executable"
```

All the macros and other such pre-processing directives are taken care at the "Pre-processing" stage itself.

Suppose, if we have several macros in source code, then will they cause any significant time in pre-processing stage?

To clarify, I am talking about the macros which are `#define`d in header file but are not `#undef`ed in that same file for some or no reason.
Due to its practicality, it will be helpful if anyone has any profiling info on this topic.

Comment: I doubt there's any general answer to this, and in practice this probably only matters if it's in a header file included by a few hundred other files. But are you comparing macros versus nothing or macros versus real functions?

Comment: @Ixrec, in a way I am comparing "more macros" with "less macros". For example, imagine in "main.h", I `#define` 100 macros. Now those macros are not `#undef`d. This file is included by all the other source files. Now this means, that each macro word has to be searched in whole source code for replacement. This can be efficient, but at least 100 such searches have to happen. Suppose, I could manage to reduce these 100 to 50, then this searches may become half. What I want to know that, does it cause any significant save in preprocessing time or just marginal?

Comment: That's not how macro replacement works. Instead, as the lexer parses tokens, it looks up the names in the macro table. The table is typically a hash table, so unless the compiler uses a poorly structured table the lookup will be O(1), i.e. roughly the same time whether you use 10 macros or 1000.

Comment: If you really want to measure the effect of macro definitions on the efficiency preprocessing, just run your compilation with the flag that signals "perform *only* preprocessing" (for GCC I think this is `-E`) and compare different versions.

Comment: You can do preprocessing independently from other compilation steps, so why not do some profiling on it.

Comment: Those are really the most boring, and least time-consuming things a compiler does. The most interesting, and most time- (and memory-)consuming things are semantic analysis (equivalent to solving the Halting Problem in the general case), type-checking (ditto), type-inference (ditto), and optimization (ditto, and even the heuristic algorithms are often NP-complete or at least exponential). You are also missing code generation, which is kind-of the most important step (after all, that's why you compile, isn't it?) but also not terribly slow, except for register-allocation (which is NP-complete).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, the preprocessing is actually happening inside the compiler (e.g. inside the `cc1plus` executable started by `g++` command). Use `g++ -C -E` to get the preprocessed form.

Preprocessing and parsing is a well known art, and does not take that much time. However, the standard headers of C++11 (e.g. `<vector>` or `<map>`) are pushing a *lot* of stuff. For example, `#include <vector>` is pushing about ten thousand lines of code on [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)/Linux with GCC 5. This is one of the reasons why compiling C++ code is slow (another reason is that C++ being incredibly context sensitive, parsing it is slow: overloaded functions, naming ambiguity, etc...).

Having many thousands of almost unused `#define`-d macros is not an issue today. (perhaps having millions of `#define` might be an issue; I leave you to try that) Look into the source code of [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or of the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) for some example.

<sup>The reason it is not a real issue today (on current laptops & desktops, with e.g. 8GBytes of RAM) is that it is mostly filling some symbol table, and these tables can routinely handle many hundred thousands symbols.</sup>

Notice that [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) take lots of time in optimization. And C++ code practically needs to be optimized (in particular, because it has lots of trivial inlinable member functions, notably in template instantiation for standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), etc...). Even C code needs to be optimized (because current superscalar out-of-order multicore pipelined processors are really different from the processors of the previous century for which C have been designed).

If you are curious about where the GCC compiler is spending its CPU time (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11338109/841108) question) pass `-freport-time` to `g++` (and also `-Wall -O2` for example). If you are even more curious, customize your GCC compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (but that requires understanding something about GCC internals, which takes weeks).

Notice that C (not C++) compilation is "fast" for its preprocessing & parsing phases (the bulk of the CPU time happens in optimization passes; experimentally, with `gcc -O2`, the compilation time is proportional to the *square* of the "size" of the largest compiled function). If you don't care about optimized code you could even try the [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) compiler (which compiles about ten times faster than GCC or Clang, but produces *slow* machine code).

Comment: +1. Pretty much everything a compiler does *except* the stages the OP listed is slow, with "slow" == "either NP-complete or solving the Halting Problem".